# Dutch passport query

Tags: passport

My grandmother was born in Dutch Sumatra. Shortly after her birth they relocated back to Holland, and she grew up in Amsterdam. Is there any possibility for me to obtain a Dutch passport?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] the question: where were you born (what nationality do you have) and what is the nationality of your parents?

Comment: The answer probably also depends on whether this grandmother is your mother's or father's mother, and possibly on the identity of that parent's father.  It could also depend on when you and your possibly-Dutch parent were born, and on whether (and, if so, when) your grandmother or your possibly-Dutch parent lost Dutch nationality.

Comment: Also, please provide details about your parents and important dates: dates of birth for your grandmother, your parent that is her child and yourself, dates of naturalization if any for her or your parents, times lived in the Netherlands, etc.